How much philosophy is about terminology and human conceptions?
I see a lot of sentences like "If a tree fell and nobody hears it did it really fall", or many questions related to infinity. But each of this questions can be true or false according to some set of axioms. Assuming we define "really fell" as the physical state of tree or whether a human saw it falling.
Or, for example, if we would take a look at the race of Achilles and the tortoise we may say that the answer is that Achilles mathematically wins. It is just impossible for our brain to make this calculation that way.
So is philosophy about things that we can prove in our physical world? Or about finding paradoxes in any system of axioms? Maybe it is about discussing the frame of our other decisions. Such as why we even care about things like that or why specific thing is considered moral or not?

Axioms don't make things true, that's apples and oranges, or logical positivism... ;)  An even more common question around here is "what is philosophy".

@JulioDiEgidio Hi thanks for the comment. But what the definition of something being true also  sound like question of something being true is matter of triminlogy . You may sometimes is true if you agree with or if it can be driven from given axioms

"Truth is one of the central subjects in philosophy": I am not sure I would agree with that, that is quite the "modern" way to see things, anyway do try and have a read through this, at least to get some more precise notions: "Truth (SEP)"

Your examples, or rather questions of this type in general, are more subtle than they seem at first glance. They cannot be resolved by definitions or axioms. There are situations where observers influence what happens so that we cannot talk of any independent "physical state". And "mathematical winning" in Achilles and the tortoise misses the point of the paradox. One of the reasons philosophy is there is to pick out what we are too tunnel visioned to notice in ordinary life, so we are less dumbfounded when something happens out of the ordinary.

Surely all philosophy is about human conceptions????
